# Abort all php Execution when click on a button or leave the page

Tags: php

Is there a way to abort a php execution when click on a button for example or when leave the actual page ?

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but it is worth reading - [Connection handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)

Comment: @nnichols I will read it, Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

In a traditional web page, you cannot as php pages are called with an http request and each http request is handled separately on the server.

Your only option would be to implement some kind a background processing which is connected to the clients through websockets. These long running processes can be stopped through the websockets channel. [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) is a product (I'm not affiliated with it in any way) that can be used to enable websockets in php.